# SQLite row number query returning a binary

Tags: android, sqlite, parseint

I am working in eclipse doing Java for Android.  I have a small sqlite database that has a method in my database manager class that is suppose to return the amount of rows in a table of the database.

That Method:

```
public int getHomeScreenTotal (){

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    int rows = -1;
    try {
       rows = (int) db.compileStatement(
       "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + homeIcons).simpleQueryForLong();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return -1;
    }
    return rows;

    }
```

problem is no matter what i do it returns a binary and not an int.  so instead of it returning 3 it returns 11, instead of 4 it returns 100, 5/ 101 ect.. ect.

As you can see i commented out int base, i was trying to force it into an in by saying:

int base =2;
int total = Integer.parseInt(bin,base);
but it was throwing errors..

Comment: what does it output if you print `c.getString(0)` ? The result of `c.getInt(0)` should already be an `int`

Answer (score 0):

I think You're returning it to a cursor when it's not giving you a cursor.  Try an int or long.

Comment: sorry, i actually had put the wrong code verion up there i updated it.. see above..  I am still getting binary results.. they are the right results, just in the wrong format